# Landing Zone vs Staging tables

Tags: data-warehouse

I am building a small DWH in SQL Server. We have 6 source tables that we have to combine into a single BASE table based on a given logic.

My question is - should I start by creating 6 LZ tables (corresponding to each of the 6 source tables) to land the data on the system. Secondly, combine these 6 LZ tables into 1 Staging table and then finally, move the data from the Staging table to the Base table ?

My first thought was to create 6 Staging tables (instead of LZ tables) and then combine these 6 to form the base table. However, I decided against it based on my understanding - that the structure of LZ tables should match the source tables and that the sructure of Staging table should refect the base tables ?

Which alternative should be pursued in this case ? What are the pros & cons ? 
Pls share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't see one single answer to this question. It really depends on various factors - frequency of extract, source system availability, complexity of transformations, data lineage requirements, etc.

I will start with creating one staging table per source system table/entity. If you are using an ETL tool do the ETL process, then most of the ETL tools are pretty good at doing simple to complex transformations "on the fly" (in memory). I have extensively used SSIS and it is pretty good at most of the transformations.

You can sometimes end up with some other tables in the staging area if your transformations have very complex business rules. It helps in debugging in the sense that you can see the data before, during and after transformations. But as I said, that really depends on the data and the transformations required.

It really is a broad question and difficult to answer in a few paragraphs but I hope it helps you in getting you started with your ETL process!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using LZ tables or datadump area, is a good idea.

First of all it provides one to one mapping with minimal transformations if any, ie adding the file name attribute.

Secondly if the process fails, before achieving another milestone, the Landing Zone tables allow for restarting the process without the need to access the data source, which may or may not be accessible at that time.

You can also archive the data from LZ tables, which, if you only taking a subset of data further down the pipeline, might save you lots of work if suddenly pipeline needs to add another attribute and the historic values are needed and the attribute is on the original files.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

In order to land the source tables , I Would Recommend you to Make Separate table for every source table .
There should be no dependency to the source table.LANDED tables would help you in making staging area.